# sql - count (if more then one) through a case

Tags: sql

The goal is to count; how many user_id's have more then one record.

the result would be: 2 
*(only one record should return)*

**THE DATA** 
user_id | value 
12 | value1 
25 | value2 
25 | value3 
17 | value4 
17 | value5

**Thank you all for your quick response!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
  SELECT user_id, count(*) 
    FROM mytable1
GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING count(*) > 1
```

-> Result all user_id, with more then one entry

or if you wanna count how many entries are not unique..

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS AreDublicate 
  FROM (
      SELECT user_id
        FROM mytable1
    GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING count(*) > 1
       ) myTable
```

-> Result how many aren't unique.. (in your case 2)

Comment: but then i need to count it all up to (as in my example) the number 2!

Comment: when i use your method i come really close, yet i get multiple record back instead of one record with a number.

Answer (score 1):

To arrive at a single number you need an inner and outer query, like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
     SELECT user_id
     FROM mytable1
     GROUP BY user_id
     HAVING count(*) > 1
     ) iq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select gt1.Id, COUNT(*)
from GroupText gt1
inner join GroupText gt2 on gt1.Id = gt2.Id and gt1.text != gt2.text
group by gt1.id
```

[image]